# Ativar / Desativar GPS no Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, gps

Olá. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de rastreamento onde em um determinado momento é feita a solicitação da localização do usuário ativando seu GPS e após isso, é feita a desativação do GPS. Em versões antigas do Android como na **2.3.3 funciona** normalmente mas na versão **4.4.2 já não funciona**. O código utilizado foi:

```
private void ativarGps() {
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (!provider.contains("gps")) {
        //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        this.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

private void desativarGPS() {
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (provider.contains("gps")) { //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        this.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Alguém saberia como resolver isso?

Answer (score 3):

A partir da versão 2.3.3, você não pode mais ativar/desativar o gps sem a aprovação do usuário.

Tudo o que você pode fazer é abrir a tela de ativação de GPS caso necessário:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean GPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if(!GPSEnabled){
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
}
```